# How to remove a string from another string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a string `BK1112-7`. I want to replace everything after the `-`, including the `-`. How do I do that ? `REPLACE()` checks for a fixed for a fixed pattern. I want the pattern to be "variable".

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('BK1112-7',0,CHARINDEX('-','BK1112-7'));
```

This will get you the value up until the -.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26791)</kbd>

To add extra information after that just do `+ 'replacement'`

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @String NVARCHAR(20); 
SET @String  = 'BK1112-7';

SELECT LEFT(@String, CHARINDEX('-', @String) - 1) + 'ReplacementString'
```

**Result**

```
BK1112ReplacementString
```